# Change background color of current section in navigation bar?

Tags: beamer

For creating a navigation bar in the header, I use:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\definecolor{headfq}{RGB}{255,0,0}   %red
\definecolor{headbg}{RGB}{249,196,95}  
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{153,255,153} %green
\definecolor{screenfoot}{RGB}{224,224,224}
\definecolor{letterfoot}{RGB}{153,0,76}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=headfq,bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{palette}{bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=letterfoot,bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{footcolor}{fg=letterfoot,bg=titlebg}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.8ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}

    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip-1pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%

    \raggedleft
    \textbf{\LARGE\insertframetitle} \hspace*{0.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

so the current section is highlighted. But how I can change the background color of this current section.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Please provide a M.W.E. It looks like beamer but I am not sure it is.

Comment: Thanks @sztruks but it's actually beamer.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the current section in a `colorbox` or similar to give it a background colour.

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\definecolor{headfq}{RGB}{255,0,0}   %red
\definecolor{headbg}{RGB}{249,196,95}  
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{153,255,153} %green
\definecolor{screenfoot}{RGB}{224,224,224}
\definecolor{letterfoot}{RGB}{153,0,76}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=headfq,bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{palette}{bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=blue,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footcolor}{fg=letterfoot,bg=titlebg}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.8ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}

    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip-1pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%

    \raggedleft
    \textbf{\LARGE\insertframetitle} \hspace*{0.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\colorbox{orange}{\insertsectionhead}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A test frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Another questions}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another test frame}Test
%\textcolor‎{‎letterfoot‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]